# How to detect/tell what Cortex A core is in Linux?

Tags: arm

I am wondering if there is a way to tell what a ARMv8 Cortex A core is, such A72, A73 or A76?

Thanks,

Comment: `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.  Tell how?  From kernel space, user space or command line?

Comment: In this platform, Linux does NOT show what type of cortex-A the CPU is.

Answer (score 0):

There is a register in ARMv8 called MIDR, where bit[15:4] holds the type of CPU, https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0595/2021-12/AArch64-Registers/MIDR-EL1--Main-ID-Register?lang=en.
For example, cortex-A76 is 0xD0B, cortex-A78AE is 0xD42